# PyQt5 Emitting action from different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to refresh a `QTableView` from a `QTableModel` updated in another thread. The QTableModel is correctly updated but nothing is emetting. I guess it is linked to multithreading but I don't find explanation or solution if I want to update my table from another thread.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTableView, QApplication, QDialog, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QVariant, QThread
import numpy as np
import threading
import sys
import time

ROWS = 2
COLUMNS = 2


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.data = np.zeros((2, 2))

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return ROWS

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return COLUMNS

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            x = index.row()
            y = index.column()
            return '{}'.format(self.data[x, y])
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def set_data(self, x, y, v):
        self.data[x, y] = v
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(x, y), self.index(x, y), [])


class TableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableView, self).__init__()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.model = TableModel()
        self.table = TableView()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.table.update)


        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    def loop():
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            window.model.set_data(np.random.randint(0,ROWS), np.random.randint(0,ROWS), np.random.randint(0, 42))

    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    t.start()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Although it is not the most elegant way, your code works for me: https://imgur.com/a/cqVz8vF

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me either @EntrustName.

Comment: @eyllanesc the table is updated instantly and automatically ? what is your config ?

Comment: I launch the application and it updates itself. I am using PyQt5 5.11

Comment: What would be a more elegant way ?

Comment: To me it seems not elegant to update it from a thread, why do you do it? On the other hand, your model has a fixed size, it should depend on the data, also if you want it to be editable you should implement the setData() method, do not create set_data( ), etc

Comment: A thread listens data from a socket. I just want to show what I get

Comment: Qt offers QTcpSocket that allows you to use sockets without the need of a thread, just using signals.

Comment: This part is independent of my program. The Listener just exposes its data and I can just add a callback method. So do you think there is a better way ?

Comment: On Mac, it is definitely doesn't work...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem thread safe at all. Is there some Python magick going on, or is it just broken? Qt objects are not thread safe by default. Make yout set_data emit signal using queued connection (which is thread safe by default), and change model in a slot which receives the signal.

Comment: Why behavior is different on some machines ? Can you provide a dummy code just to understand ? thanks